# Splitting a string on the first space

Tags: regex, r

I'd like to split a vector of character strings (people's names) into two columns (vectors).  The problem is some people have a 'two word' last name.  I'd like to split the first and last names into two columns.  I can slit out and take the first names using the code below but the last name eludes me. (look at obs 29 in the sample set below to get an idea as the Ford has a "last name" of Pantera L that must be kept together)

What I have attempted to do so far;

```
x<-rownames(mtcars)
unlist(strsplit(x, " .*"))
```

What I'd like it to look like:

```
            MANUF       MAKE
27          Porsche     914-2
28          Lotus       Europa
29          Ford        Pantera L
30          Ferrari     Dino
31          Maserati    Bora
32          Volvo       142E
```

Answer (score 32, accepted):

The regular expression `rexp` matches the word at the start of the string, an optional space, then the rest of the string.  The parenthesis are subexpressions accessed as backreferences `\\1` and `\\2`.

```
rexp <- "^(\\w+)\\s?(.*)$"
y <- data.frame(MANUF=sub(rexp,"\\1",x), MAKE=sub(rexp,"\\2",x))
tail(y)
#       MANUF      MAKE
# 27  Porsche     914-2
# 28    Lotus    Europa
# 29     Ford Pantera L
# 30  Ferrari      Dino
# 31 Maserati      Bora
# 32    Volvo      142E
```

Answer (score 21):

For me, Hadley's `colsplit` function in the `reshape2` package is the most intuitive for this purpose. Joshua's way is more general (ie can be used wherever a regex could be used) and flexible (if you want to change the specification); but the `colsplit` function is perfectly suited to this specific setting:

```
library(reshape2)
y <- colsplit(x," ",c("MANUF","MAKE"))
tail(y)
#      MANUF      MAKE
#27  Porsche     914-2
#28    Lotus    Europa
#29     Ford Pantera L
#30  Ferrari      Dino
#31 Maserati      Bora
#32    Volvo      142E
```

Comment: +1 Really interesting, since I had assumed `colsplit` will return more than three columns in this case.  How wrong I was.

Comment: I spent 50 minutes to find the solution to this extremely simple task. I am really surprised by how complicated it is to solve such simple tasks.

Answer (score 13):

Here are two approaches:

**1) strsplit**.  This approach uses only functions in the core of R and no complex regular expressions. Replace the first space with a semicolon (using `sub` and *not* `gsub`), `strsplit` on the semicolon and then `rbind` it into a 2 column matrix:

```
mat <- do.call("rbind", strsplit(sub(" ", ";", x), ";"))
colnames(mat) <- c("MANUF", "MAKE")
```

**2) strapply in gsubfn package**  Here is a one-liner using `strapply` in the gsubfn package. The two parenthesized portions of the regular expression capture the desired first and second columns respectively and the function (which is specified in formula notation -- its the same as specifying `function(x, y) c(MANUF = x, MAKE = y)`) grabs them and adds names.  The `simplify=rbind` argument is to used to turn it into a matrix as in the prior solution.

```
library(gsubfn)
mat <- strapply(x, "(\\S+)\\s+(.*)", ~ c(MANUF = x, MAKE = y), simplify = rbind)
```

*Note:* In either case a `"character"` matrix, `mat`, is returned.  If a data frame of `"character"` columns is desired then add this:

```
DF <- as.data.frame(mat, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Omit the `stringsAsFactors` argument if `"factor"` columns are wanted.

Comment: I just checked back here.  I actually wound up liking your #1 solution the best of any supplied.  Thanks and sorry for the later return.

Answer (score 9):

Yet another way of doing it:

`str_split` from `stringr` will handle the split, but returns it in a different form (a list, like `strsplit` does).  Manipulating into the correct form is straightforward though.

```
library(stringr)
split_x <- str_split(x, " ", 2)
(y <- data.frame(
  MANUF = sapply(split_x, head, n = 1),
  MAKE  = sapply(split_x, tail, n = 1)
))
```

---

Or, as Hadley mentioned in the comments, with `str_split_fixed`.

```
y <- as.data.frame(str_split_fixed(x, " ", 2))
colnames(y) <- c("MANUF", "MAKE")
y
```

Comment: It's interesting to note that this answer + hadley's comment is related to the `colsplit` solution because `colsplit` uses `str_split_fixed`.

Answer (score 0):

If you can do pattern and group matching, I'd try something like this (untested):

```
\s+(.*)\s+(.*)
```

Comment: Just so you know, regex's in R work a little differently. At the very least, you'd need to add another \ in front of each s, just to avoid an error.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use tidyr::extract after converting your vector into a data frame first - I think this would also be the more modern version of older solutions with reshape2

```r
library(tidyr)

## first convert into a data frame
x <- data.frame(x = rownames(mtcars))

## use extract, and for example Joshua's regex
res <- extract(x, col = x, into = c("MANUF", "MAKE"), regex = "^(\\w+)\\s?(.*)$")

head(res)
#>     MANUF       MAKE
#> 1   Mazda        RX4
#> 2   Mazda    RX4 Wag
#> 3  Datsun        710
#> 4  Hornet    4 Drive
#> 5  Hornet Sportabout
#> 6 Valiant
```

Answer (score -2):

I think searching for `[^\s]+` would work. Untested.