# Extract all matching pattern from a character vector

Tags: r, regex, string, stringr

I have this vector :

```
 [1] "capacit_elab_doc_Ne sait pas du tout le faire"     "capacit_elab_doc_Pas tres a l aise"               
 [3] "capacit_elab_doc_Moyennement a l aise"             "capacit_elab_doc_Plutot a l aise"                 
 [5] "capacit_elab_doc_Tres a l aise"                    "capacit_rech_info_Ne sait pas du tout le faire"   
 [7] "capacit_rech_info_Pas tres a l aise"               "capacit_rech_info_Moyennement a l aise"
```

I would like to match these values :

```
[1] "capacit_elab_doc"     "capacit_rech_info"    "capacit_eval_info"    "capacit_id_numerique"
```

To get this output :

```
[1] "capacit_elab_doc"  "capacit_elab_doc"  "capacit_elab_doc" 
[4] "capacit_elab_doc"  "capacit_elab_doc"  "capacit_rech_info"
[7] "capacit_rech_info" "capacit_rech_info"
```

How can I do that ? I would prefer a stringr solution.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8300837/9076343

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try the following base R solution using `regmatches`

```
unlist(regmatches(v,gregexpr(paste0(pat,collapse = "|"),v)))

# [1] "capacit_elab_doc"  "capacit_elab_doc"  "capacit_elab_doc"  "capacit_elab_doc"  "capacit_elab_doc" 
# [6] "capacit_rech_info" "capacit_rech_info" "capacit_rech_info"
```

where `v` is the vector of strings and `pat` denotes all patterns.

**DATA**

```
v <- c("capacit_elab_doc_Ne sait pas du tout le faire", "capacit_elab_doc_Pas tres a l aise", 
"capacit_elab_doc_Moyennement a l aise", "capacit_elab_doc_Plutot a l aise", 
"capacit_elab_doc_Tres a l aise", "capacit_rech_info_Ne sait pas du tout le faire", 
"capacit_rech_info_Pas tres a l aise", "capacit_rech_info_Moyennement a l aise"

pat <- c("capacit_elab_doc", "capacit_rech_info", "capacit_eval_info", 
"capacit_id_numerique")
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not simply :

```r
stringr::str_match(string = your_vector,
                   pattern = "^capacit_elab_doc*|^capacit_rech_info*|^capacit_eval_info*|^capacit_id_numerique*") %>% as.vector
```

Answer (score 0):

This way uses a regex with a negative lookahead `(?=_)` to match everything up until the third underscore.

```r
library(stringr)

text <- list("capacit_elab_doc_Ne sait pas du tout le faire", "capacit_elab_doc_Pas tres a l aise", "capacit_elab_doc_Moyennement a l aise", "capacit_elab_doc_Plutot a l aise", "capacit_elab_doc_Tres a l aise", "capacit_rech_info_Ne sait pas du tout le faire", "capacit_rech_info_Pas tres a l aise", "capacit_rech_info_Moyennement a l aise") 

lapply(text, function(x) str_extract(x, "(.*_.*_.*)(?=_)"))
#> [[1]]
#> [1] "capacit_elab_doc"
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> [1] "capacit_elab_doc"
#> 
#> [[3]]
#> [1] "capacit_elab_doc"
#> 
#> [[4]]
#> [1] "capacit_elab_doc"
#> 
#> [[5]]
#> [1] "capacit_elab_doc"
#> 
#> [[6]]
#> [1] "capacit_rech_info"
#> 
#> [[7]]
#> [1] "capacit_rech_info"
#> 
#> [[8]]
#> [1] "capacit_rech_info"
```

<sup>Created on 2020-02-05 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

If you insist on `stringr`, one way would be:

```
stringr::str_match(your_vector, '(.*)_.*')[,2]
```

Otherwise just `sub('(.*)_.*', '\\1', your_vector)` would do it.